# get value from child component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and need some help to my specific situation. I have a top-level app.js where I render

```
export default class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentGuess: '',
        historicGuess: '',
        result: ''
    };
  }

  handleCurrentGuess(event) {
    console.log(event)
    this.setState({currentGuess: event.target.value})
  }

  handleSend() {
    console.log(this.state.currentGuess)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <Header />
            <Logic handleCurrentGuess={this.handleCurrentGuess}/>
            <Result />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The component has to be stateful, and I enter the currentGuess value into state.

The `<Logic />` looks like this:

```
export default function Logic(props) {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div className="logic">
        <form>
            <input type="text" onChange={props.handleCurrentGuess}/>
            <button onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                props.handleSend
            }}>Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The issue now is that I cannot find documentation on how to pass both pass the function on to the  AND get returned a value from the input. Most docs show onChange via the input directly, but I want to fetch the value ONLY when someone clicks on the submit button (or hits enter). So,

how do I pass the correct function to the child, and how do I get the text value back on button press within the Logic component?

Comment: Just asking to understand you better. So, you want the value pass to parent only clicking the button in the child right? Then, you can define a state in the child, after handling input you can pass the value back. But, this is not necessary and your logic is so right now. Why do you need something like this?

Comment: You can use a callback, passed in via props to your child component to pass state to the parent component

Comment: The user enters a number into input, and when they click the button i need the value of the input passed to the state in the top-level component

Comment: By saying "top-level" component do you mean a different component rendering `Page`?

Comment: @devserkan No, top-level component is referring to `class Page extends React.Component` in line 1

Comment: I'm confused. You are already doing this with `onChange` in your `Logic` component. With the change of input, your `currentGuess` is being updated.

Comment: This is how I understand it so far: If i have an onChange on the input, the value get's updated on every key stroke. If that is the case then nothing would update on the button click though?

Comment: Yes, button is needles there right now. But this is a very common pattern usage for inputs if you write them a separate component. You can do what you want here but it needs holding another state in the `Logic` component and this unnecessary here I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176838/discussion-between-devserkan-and-helle).

Comment: ok, going to wait in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `console.log` the state right now (for testing purposes obviously) here is the two problems with your code.

First, you are not passing your `handleSend` function as a prop to `Logic` component.
Second, on your button, you are not invoking this `handleSend` function in your onClick handler.

Here is a working example.

```js
const Logic = props => (
    <div className="logic">
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={props.handleCurrentGuess} />
        <button onClick={props.handleSend}>Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );

class Page extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentGuess: '',
    historicGuess: '',
    result: ''
  };

  handleCurrentGuess = event =>
    this.setState({ currentGuess: event.target.value })

  handleSend = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.currentGuess)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Logic
        handleCurrentGuess={this.handleCurrentGuess}
        handleSend={this.handleSend} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I slightly changed the code. Use some arrow functions so no need to `.bind` them, remove the unnecessary constructor, use class-fields, etc. I also used the function reference for `onClick` in the button.